# uint not convertible to int

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I just want to print the children count and set it to label.

This is my JSON structure:

- simplelogin2

  - name
  - age
  - post

    - post1: "asdasd"
    - post2: "sadasd"
    - post3: "asdasd"

I want to print the count of children in post or set it to a label How should I do it?

I tried this:

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(ref.authData.uid).childByAppendingPath("post").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    self.postCount = snapshot.childrenCount.value
    println(self.postCount)

})'
```

but it says word is not convertible to uint.

UPDATE :

this is how i created user  :

```
  var userId = authData.uid

                        let newUser = [
                            "Provider" : authData.provider,
                            "email"    : authData.providerData["email"] as? NSString as? String,
                            "name"     : self.Name.text,
                            "Image"    : "",
                            "location" : "",
                            "about"    : "",
                            "age"      : "",
                        ]


self.ref.childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(authData.uid).setValue(newUser)
```

this is how i added the child "post" to every user!

(inside a button i did this coding)

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("users/\(ref.authData.uid)/post").childByAutoId().setValue(text.text)
```

Comment: i did it in this way bcoz i want to print the childrens count of post of a logged in user!

Comment: the question is ambiguous

Comment: post more code or show the error

Comment: my question is that how do i get the children count of a child of a user!

Comment: You need to show more code. We need to see the definition of snapshot to determine how you can get a count of its children.

Comment: i have edited my question check it i have added more code @MrBeardsley

Comment: so every user that logs  in when presses that button it adds a child to the post path of that particular user!

Comment: now that i have given you the code can you tell me how do i get the children count displayed on a label? @MrBeardsley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Firebase documentation, childrenCount is an NSUInteger.

```
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSUInteger childrenCount
```

I would drop the .value call as its not needed. You can also use string interpolation to turn values into strings.

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(ref.authData.uid).childByAppendingPath("post").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    self.postCount = snapshot.childrenCount
    println("\(self.postCount)")
})
```

If you have a UILabel somewhere that you want to set the postCount as the text, do the following. Note, for the example my UILabel is called just label.

```
label?.text = "\(self.postCount)"
```

Notice the question mark on label. Since text is an optional property, we use optional chaining to set the value.

Comment: thankyou for replying but using your code it is displaying nil on the label

Comment: and one more thing that  when i typed println("\(self.postcount)") out of the singleevent method but inside the view did load it is giving me nil and if i type it in the singleEvent method it is printing the count correctly.. now what do i do ? @Mr Beardsley

Comment: thank you sir ! it worked :) i set the label to postCount inside the SingleEventMethod ... thanks again :)

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it worked. Sorry for the delay in getting you an answer.